# Tweet to twitter user via href

Tags: html, twitter, hyperlink

Just a quick one, how can i tweet to a user direct from an a href link on my site? example:

```
<a href="twitter.com/user?newtweet=">@name</a>
```

Hope you understand what i'm after! Not sure if it can be done

Comment: Can't be done that simply. You may want to look into the [Twitter API](http://dev.twitter.com)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the closest you will get is using the [Twitter Tweet buttons](https://twitter.com/about/resources/buttons), unless you want to write your own backend-service that you can access through HTTP GET, which in turn will have to interact with Twitter through their API.

Using the above referenced code-generator, you would get a code that looks something like this, where you would have to swap `c_eliasson` which is my Twitter-handle with the one you would like to use instead:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?screen_name=c_eliasson" class="twitter-mention-button" data-related="c_eliasson">Tweet to @c_eliasson</a>

<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

*I would recommend using the code-generator though, as it gives you some additional opportunities to customize the look and behavior of it.*

Comment: Thank you, have just seen your response after i posted my own! haha

Comment: @AndyHolmes My pleasure! Notice that you have to include the script tag as well. Using just the anchor as described in your own answer will not be sufficient I believe.

Comment: I just tested, takes you straight to the tweet page :)
EDIT: This is what i am after as client requested no pop ups, just so you know

Comment: @AndyHolmes I see, glad you found what you were looking for.

Answer (score 4):

upon looking at the twitter buttons as suggested, you can simply just use

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?screen_name=@twittername">Tweet to @twittername</a>
```

Comment: Tweet Web Intent [developer guide](https://dev.twitter.com/web/tweet-button/web-intent)

Comment: [Here](https://ww2.younoodle.com/2013/09/10/how-create-a-pre-populated-tweet/) are some tips for this method, including how to include hashtags.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?screen_name=c_eliasson" class="twitter-mention-button" data-related="c_eliasson"> Tweet to @twitteralbgoom </a> <script> !function(d,s,id){ var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];

 if(!d.getElementById(id))
{ js=d.createElement(s); 
js.id=id; 
js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);
}
}
(document,"script","twitter-wjs"); </script>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?screen_name=c_eliasson" class="twitter-mention-button" data-related="c_eliasson">
  Tweet to @twitteralbgoom
</a>

<script>
  !function(d,s,id){
    var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if(!d.getElementById(id)){
      js=d.createElement(s);
      js.id=id;
      js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");
</script>
```